# Can you use CDC on a subscriber for transactional replicaiton

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, change-data-capture, change-tracking

Is there a way with SQL Server to have a limited number of tables replicated to another server using transactional replication and then use CDC or Change Tracking ONLY in the server replicated to?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention whether you are using SQL Server 2012 or 2014, however the documentation on CDC and Change Tracking do not show much difference.

Both make the following statement: "CDC configuration is always performed on the current or intended **primary replica**."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403414(v=sql.120).aspx#CDC

The above link is for SQL Server 2014 and offers many more details.

Comment: That link refers to CDC in the context of replication with Availability Groups. Is the same relevant outside of AGs?

Comment: So basically if you are setting up a HA cluster using AGs and you want CDC you configure that one the primary.  But to reiterate what Mark said what if I don't want CDC on the HA cluster but rather to another server that is getting tables replicated to it via transactional replication

Comment: Are you trying to use AGs?

Comment: No... I have 2 servers that are in an AG but I want to replicate 5-6 tables from that server to another DB and then have change tracking on those tables on JUST the other server.  I don't want change tracking on... on the HA cluster.